# Regex to extract parts of string

Tags: regex

I'm setting up some campaign codes which will appear as a query parameter in a URL.  I'd like to automate the reporting of these campaign codes and have set them up in such a way that each parameter within the code has a specific set of values, which are recognised in the system via a look up.  However, the end part of the string is free text.  Here's an example:

```
socfb:obb:img:beg:rp:lo:mff:mffs201403_sbj1
```

As explained previously parameters 1-7 can be a number of different values that are already known to the system and I can just use a contains query to extract each of these values and use them in a look up to get their report friendly names.  However, how can I extract the last part of the string eg `mffs201403_sbj1` which is optional, but will always be free text with variable length and will always appear after the 7th colon.

In addition, is there a way to capture the `mffs201403` bit only where I always use an underscore to separate the two parts at the end?  This is because the first part identifies an individual campaign, where as the second part identifies a variant of that campaign, if it exists.  So I'd like to report on all campaign variants, e.g. `mffs201403_sbj1`, `mffs201403_sbj2`, etc, as well as `mffs201403` as a whole.

I been trying to get my head around Regex for the longest time and I've been unable to master it, so if anyone can help me with this I'd be extremely grateful

Comment: So just to make sure I understand your question, you want to extract the last part eg. `mffs201403` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply... I'd like to extract 'mffs201403' and mffs201403_xxxx... Thanks. I'd like to create two reports Campaign names and Campaign Name Variants... Thank you

Comment: What language are you using to process the regex? I ask because some implementations have slight differences between them and because you're getting answers targeting a few different languages. The regex should generally be valid, regardless of the language surrounding it, but it might be practical to specify just in case.

Comment: @MattChampion I'm using a function which is available in the web analytics tool I am using. I am not sure which language it has been written in. I just need to enter the regex for any output I am looking for.  So I'd need to write two separate regex's. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Amara It might be worth adding details of which web analytics tool you're using into the question itself, and adding the relevant tag if one is available. That way, if there are any specifics that need to be considered due to the tool that you're using, those answering can attempt to point them out.

Comment: @Matt Champion, I can't seem to add any additional tags now, but it is Adobe Site Catalyst. The interface provides the ability to add regex for variable classification purposes.

Comment: @Amara I don't really know anything about Adobe Site Catalyst, but would either [tag:business-catalyst] or [tag:adobe-analytics] be relevant? Those seem to be common tags for questions related to Adobe Site Catalyst at least. Either way, I would recommend editing your question to specify that you're using Adobe Site Catalyst, as well as the other requirements that you've specified in comments to the different answers (such as needing "a separate regex for each").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you use, but this works fine in c#:

```
var input = "socfb:obb:img:beg:rp:lo:mff:mffs201403_sbj1";
var pattern = "^(?:[^:]+:){7}(?<last>(?<part1>[^_]+)_(?<part2>[^_]+))+$";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Last: {0}", match.Groups["last"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Part1: {0}", match.Groups["part1"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Part2: {0}", match.Groups["part2"].Value);
}
```

It outputs:

```
Last: mffs201403_sbj1
Part1: mffs201403
Part2: sbj1
```

The regex works by finding "any characters other than `:`" followed by a `:`, and repeats this 7 times. Then it looks for "any character other than `_`", divided by a `_`, and puts the last parts in separate subgroups to easily extract them in code.

If you use some kind of third party tool that just takes a regex, i guess this will work better:

```
^(?:[^:]+:){7}([^_]*)_?([^_]*)$
```

The subgroups 1 and 2 will contain the two parts of the last variable, but it will also handle cases where there is no last variable, or it doesn't contain a `_`, or any of the parts before and after the `_` is empty.

In order to just match the last variable, and nothing else, this regex can be used:

```
[^:]*$
```

$ is the end of the string, and we match everything before this that isn't a `:`.

However, to match something in the middle of the string, without also matching the surrounding characters, it gets a bit tricky, and maybe even impossible with regex. If you know that the string will never contain any `_`, except for in the last variable, you could use:

```
[^:]*_
```

Which works pretty much the same, but will always include the `_` in the match.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using an inbuilt capability within an analytics tool interface.  So I'd have to write regex separately.  Also the campaign name part and the variant part can be of variable length.  Is there a regex for each of these?

Comment: The part1 & part2 subgroups can be of any length between 1 and infinity, the pattern will still match.

Comment: @Amara: Answer updated with a simplified version that might work better for you

Comment: Thanks @TheQ, I've tested it and it works and I get 3 match groups. But what I need to enter is a separate regex for each.  So what would the regex be for each one specifically? So to get Last alone and then Part 1 alone what regex would I write for each one?  Sorry if I'm being a little slow, but for each regex I need one result... Thank you

Comment: What I need is one regex to get mffs201403 and one for mffs201403_sbj1 as they need to be entered separately to create two different sets of classifications... Thank you

Comment: I understand, that will make it a bit more tricky, since we need to use parts of the string that you don't want in the match in order to match it correctly. Extracting mffs201403_sbj1 is easy, [^:]*$ should work. But i'm not really sure how to only get the first part without matching the rest.. Maybe if it's always in the same format, 4 letters, 6 numbers, then \w{4}\d{6} would work, but that might match other parts of the string as well if they happen to contain the same pattern.

Comment: Added some more info to the answer. [^:]*_ might solve the last part.

Comment: Hi, I've been able to use the first solution you gave and the second solution to get the regex's I need... I can in fact use the groups given within the interface.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Something like so should work for you: `(\w+:){7}([^_]+)_(\w+)`.

This regular expression expects to find a string which is separated by an underscore after a repetition of 7 groups of word characters (denoted by `\w` which means upper case letters, lower case letters numbers and underscores).

If the last segment does not exist, then, the regular expression will fail. A working example can be found [here](http://regex101.com/r/mH7kM0/1).

In Java this would translate to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+:){7}([^_]+)_(\\w+)");
    String str1 = "socfb:obb:img:beg:rp:lo:mff:mffs201403_sbj1";
    String str2 = "socfb:obb:img:beg:rp:lo:mff";

    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(str1);
    if(m1.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m1.group(2));
        System.out.println(m1.group(3));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No content found for " + str1);
    }

    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(str2);
    if(m2.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m2.group(2));
        System.out.println(m2.group(3));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No content found for " + str2);
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
mffs201403
sbj1
No content found for socfb:obb:img:beg:rp:lo:mff
```

Comment: Thank you, but the last part of the string can be of variable length

Comment: @Amara: I am not making any assumptions on the length of the string, just that there must be 7 text values followed by semi colons prior to the text you would like to match, which can also not exist, in which case, I presume that the last semi colon will be missing.

Comment: ITYM _colons_, not _semi colons_. Semicolon is `;`.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for pointing it out. For some reason, it seems I cannot edit my own comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a direct answer to your quesion but: If this is done within a script then you don't really need to use a regex. Whichever programming language you're using should have a string splitting function which will be easier to use and much more readable.

For example in python:

```
strings = query_parameter.split(":")
final_string = strings[-1]
```

then to split up that string:

```
campaign = final_string.split("_")[0]
try:
    variant = final_string.split("_")[1]
except IndexError:
    variant = ""
```